# KML Layers ArcGIS JS API v4 (beta)

Tags: javascript, beta, arcgis-js-api

I am working with the new ArcGIS JavaScript API v4 which is still in it's beta. I have been using KML Layers in the previous version to bring in my layers from ArcGIS, however the format for this one seems to be a bit different and I can't quite figure it out.

Here is the code to implement this in v3:

```
require([
  "esri/layers/KMLLayer", ... 
], function(KMLLayer, ... ) {
  var kmlUrl = 'kml url here';
  kml = new KMLLayer(kmlUrl);
  ...
});
```

I cannot find anything for KML Layer additions in the new version. Has anyone else found anything?

Answer (score 0):

I am also interested to use this function. However, to my understanding, the function for kml layers has not been added yet in v4. It was said that all available functions were in the reference, but kml is not in the list.